# How to Edit JTable KeyBinding for F2

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, key-bindings

I want to change the editor for a single cell to start when the ctrl key is clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: *"How can I do this?"*  What have you tried?  It would seem that plugging keybinding and Java into a search engine should lead to some [good resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: You could look at the [TableCellEditor#isCellEditable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable(java.util.EventObject))

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for some examples of how to reuse/reassign an Action with a KeyStroke.